# How to insert a unicode special character in QString?

Tags: qt, unicode, qstring

I am trying to insert a special unicode character (0xFD3F) into a QString.

I tried to create `QChar(0xFD3F)` but when outputting this char and viewing it in a hex editor it shows `0x3F3F`. 
I couldn't also find a function in `QString` to insert a character by its hex or decimal representation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `QString::fromUtf8` like this:

`QString::fromUtf8("Hello \uFD3F  Good bye")`

Comment: I think the problem is in the character itself and I am trying to figure out why it is doing this

Comment: Is this the only character that behaves like that in your hex editor? If you print it normally (just on the terminal), does it print the correct character? (i.e. does it print ")"?)

Comment: My bad, you are absolutely right. I was making two mistakes, first I was writing a stream for testing without setting the codec to UTF-8, second I was expecting to find 0xFD 0x3F in hex editor while `FD3F` is the unicode point not the encoding in UTF-8. The actual encoding in UTF-8 is `0xEF 0xB4 0xBF`. I am starting to understand the difference between the Unicode and the encoding. For any one wants to know read this http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html. Thank you @excalibur your answer is right!

Answer (score 5):

Use QString::fromWCharArray like this:

```
QString::fromWCharArray(L"Hello \uFD3F  Good bye")
```

Comment: Sorry @Vladislav. Only 0x3F also. But thank you for introducing this way to me.

Comment: Your answer is right the problem was with me. I would accept it but @excalibur1491 answered a right answer before you. Any way thank you and good luck with raising your score I am sure you will earn a high score :).